# How to break out SMD chips in-circuit?

Tags: measurement, surface-mount, prototyping, breakout

For a current project I am attempting to amplify and cross-wire the signals from the address pins of SMD RAM chips. Basically this means I am trying to break out the pins of a SMD chip, similar to how one would do with a SMD breakout board for prototyping, except in this case the SMD chip is soldered and operational in-circuit. I want to be able to measure the signals and interconnect them in a ***stable*** way --- at the moment I am soldering magnet wire to the individual pins and it is incredibly fragile and the soldering itself immensely difficult.

The chips I am attempting to break out are in a 0.8mm pitch 50pin TSOP II package (see attached image). Perhaps there is a custom option? Or some other clever solution?

Your thoughts and suggestions are very appreciated.

[image: TSOP II 50 pin 0.8mm pitch DRAM chips]

Comment: Why can't you just use one of those SMD clips?

Comment: What's incredibly fragile about soldering magnet wire (or wire-wrap wire) to the pins? You just have to button down the other end (connect to a perf board etc. that's double-faced taped or screwed to the DUT) and then it should be dead easy and quite reliable (especially on the bench). If your eyes are not good enough, use a decent stereo microscope to assist with the soldering. 0.5mm pitch is a bit tougher, but doable.

Comment: I don't know what you actually want to do with those SDRAM chips, but trying to trace 66..133MHz signals without disturbing them is a non-trivial task.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I've searched for TSOP-50 SMD clips but with no luck finding something so fine. (or within my budget)

Comment: @Spehro Good tips, though when I'm soldering I always create bridges between pins, connecting wires to adjacent pins is nearly impossible. Maybe my hands are not steady enough or soldering iron tip not fine enough.

Comment: @JCR That's what the handy roll of solder wick is for.

Comment: @Laszlo The chips are VRAM on iMac G3 computers made in the early 2000's. I'm cross-wiring / ground shunting address pins in order to create visual distortions for an artwork. My knowledge of transmission line analysis is prettymuch nil, but soldering enameled wire to some of the pins seems to have worked so far. Still I'd like to be able to reliably break out more than just a few of the pins without running into problems of solder bridges and fragile magnet wire. I've destroyed a few chips trying to solder wick away some bridges.. maybe I'm not so good at that :-)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how stable you are looking for, you may look at the example of "Bunnie" Huang's tap for the Xbox.  This was to tap a 200 MHz bus to memory.  He did this with a small PCB, one side shaved at an angle epoxied to the motherboard.  By wicking solder between the exposed traces of the motherboard and the card.

The picture of the motherboard you posted doesn't have the nicely parallel top-layer bus, but I thought it was a neat idea.

[image: Tap board]

> The Tap Board has on one edge a pattern of traces with no soldermask
>   that matches the pattern of traces on the Xbox motherboard. The Tap
>   Board was soldered directly to the Xbox’s northbridge-southbridge bus.
>   Only the receive-direction Tap Board was mounted for this study. The
>   mating edge was shaped using a belt sander, so that the tapping traces
>   were flush with the edge of the board, and the board could be mounted
>   at a reclined angle to enhance solderability. The soldermask on the
>   Xbox was removed with fine-grit sand paper, and the Tap Board was
>   carefully aligned by hand, and then held roughly in place by soldering
>   a coarse piece of wire between the Tap Board and the motherboard. A
>   hard-setting adhesive, such as Miller-Stephenson Epoxy 907, was
>   applied to fix the angle and mating distance of the Tap board to the
>   motherboard; once the epoxy was cured, the holding wire was removed,
>   and the traces between the Tap Board and the Xbox motherboard were
>   easily soldered using a fine-tip iron and a microscope.

from [Keeping Secrets in Hardware: the Microsoft XBoxTM Case Study, Page 7](ftp://publications.ai.mit.edu/ai-publications/2002/AIM-2002-008.pdf) by Andrew “bunnie” Huang

---

On the commercially available side of house, [several](https://www.emulation.com/catalog/off-the-shelf_solutions/debugging_accessories/test_clips/tsop_II/) [companies](http://www.adapt-plus.com/products_html/8800-0109.html) make TSOP probes for a pretty reasonable price for commercial work (~$800).

[image: TSOP 50 probe]

Comment: Thanks! Both for the clever solution and the more expensive one, I wasn't able to find TSOP probes anywhere. With the Xbox tap were there no problems with signal reflections? I'd love to try something like that if it can be squeezed on to the board I'm using between the pins and surrounding components.

Comment: @JCR, there are still issues with reflections since it is still a stub.  They are just far attenuated as compared to the 4 foot stub you would have with a standard probe since he was using a chip on the PCB as a buffer.  For a PCB solution, you could do something clever (http://www.beldynsys.com/chipchanger.htm or http://logic-analyzer-adapter.com/soic_monitor.html) or if you have a reflow station, you could make a pcb which replaces the chip and provides tap access which is soldered like a QFN.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove the current chip
2. lift the pins in question on a new chip
3. solder in the new chip, not soldering the lifted pins to the pads on the board
4. solder in wire leads to the lifted pins (wire wrap wire?)
5. test
6. conformal coat the solder connections to protect them